# LAN tester shows two light at the same time

Tags: lan

Can someone help me please. I have crimped both ends nicely. When I test it using my LAN tester, one end glows nicely from 1 to 8 but the other end glows 1&2 at the same time. I have tested the tester with another cable and it works perfectly fine. I have crimped for more that 20 times and each time I get the same result. What can I do to overcome this issue? THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspect the length of cable- is it pinched or damaged at any point?

It sounds like pins 1 and 2 are shorting out somewhere. Hopefully it's happening close to one of the ends, so you can cut off the damaged section and recrimp.

If the cable is stapled to a wall or in a place where it might have been stepped on a few times, then that might help you narrow down where the damage occurred.

How long is the cable? For me, if it was a relatively short length (25ft or less), I would rather throw it out than risk introducing a problem into my network.

Cables are pretty cheap these days but reliability is priceless!

***EDIT*** (moving my solution into my answer- originally posted it as a comment)

Just recrimp using a non-standard configuration. I doubt you're using CAT6 cables (most people don't, especially at home), in which case only pins 1+2 and 3+6 are in use. Pins 4,5,7 and 8 don't carry a signal. Keep pins 3 and 6 as they are, then replace 1 and 2 with 7 and 8 (or 4 and 5) and you should have a perfectly functional cable.

Potentially you could have this fixed in 10-20 minutes!

When testing the cable afterwards with your tester, just make sure 1,2,3 and 6 function properly, and ignore what results the others give you. You can definitely fix it. 6 of the internal wires are good- and you only need 4. When I did this myself I made sure 1,2,3 and 6 matched up, then literally plugged the rest in randomly (just to keep them out of the way) and it's worked great since then.

Comment: You might consider cutting it exactly in half if you are at the point of tossing it as one of the two halves is not like the other.

Comment: That's a good idea. Most likely there is only a single problem- so half the cable is probably perfect. Testing should confirm this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer d-man. I wish I could replace the cable and not go through all the hassle but he thing is that the cable is about 30 meters and it is run though the walls. I asked my electrician to run this cable for me from the room where I have my modem to the living room where the tv is. I was planning to connect my tv through ethernet to the internet. So I guess this is not happening huh?

Comment: Ok this is an interesting one. You can very easily fix it!

Just recrimp using a non-standard configuration.

I doubt you're using CAT6 cables (most people don't, especially at home), in which case only pins 1+2 and 3+6 are in use. Pins 4,5,7 and 8 don't carry a signal.

Keep pins 3 and 6 as they are, then replace 1 and 2 with 7 and 8 (or 4 and 5) and you should have a perfectly functional cable.

Potentially you could have this fixed in 10-20 minutes! When testing the cable afterwards with your tester, just make sure 1,2,3 and 6 function properly, and ignore what results the others give you.

Comment: No Im pretty sure Im using CAT5. It will be brilliant if I can get this to work following your instructions. So the configuration would look like Brown/White-Brown-Green/White-Blue-Blue/White-Green-Orange/White-Orange, right? Will let you know the outcome later on. Thanks

Comment: Yep, you can definitely fix it. 6 of the internal wires are good- and you only need 4.

When I did this myself I made sure 1,2,3 and 6 matched up, then literally plugged the rest in randomly (just to keep them out of the way) and it's worked great since then.

Comment: I dont know how to thank you d-man. Its working fine thanks to your help...

Comment: Good job! It's easy when you realize only 4 out of 8 pins are used. Could you vote my answer as "accepted answer" so I can get a few extra points? :D

Comment: @Austin''Danger''Powers is it possible to to the same with a Cat6 cable and have it running as a 100Mb cable? Seems like my cable has a short circuity between orange, green and white/brown (3 wires).